# Find all function(maybe complex) $f$ with this property,

Tags: analysis, functional-equations

This is a part of a stochastic process exercise.
Here $f$ is not a constant and $\forall s, t, x,$ we have
$$f(s + x)f(t + x) = f(s)f(t).$$
It is required to find all $f$.

If $s = t$, I can get the relation $f(s+x) = \pm f(s)$, so $f$ is a function with two values $\pm z$, where $z$ is a complex constant. Moreover $f$ has some property like periodicity (or translation invariance), but I can't imagine a way to prove it.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: Translation invariance would certainly suffice.

Comment: When you say "complex" $f$, I assume you mean the outputs are complex.  But what are the inputs?

Comment: Note that the value of the constant isn't important.  If $f$ is a solution, so is $\lambda f$ for all constants $\lambda \neq 0$ so you can just take $z=1$.  ($z$ can't be $0$, else the function is constant).

Comment: Sry the inputs are real.

Comment: So is there some non-constant function satisfy this constraint?

Answer (score 5):

Taking $s = 0$ and $t = x$ we get $f(x) f(2x) = f(0) f(x)$, so if $f$ is not $0$ we get $f(2x) = f(0)$.  But that says $f$ is constant.